# Dynamic content and full page cache

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, cache, full-page-cache

I have dynamic content in my block which is cached so I exclude this block from cache in the easiest way. I've created cache.xml which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <placeholders>
         <my_category_view>
            <block>catalog/category_view</block>
            <placeholder>MY_CATEGORY_VIEW</placeholder>
            <container>Custom_Package_Model_Container_Category_View</container>
            <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
        </my_category_view>
    </placeholders>
</config>
```

and i've created container:

```
class My_Package_Model_Container_Category_View extends
  My_Page_Model_Container_Abstract
    {
           const PREFIX = 'MY_CATEGORY_VIEW';
    }
```

and it works great. the block is excluded from FPC, but the problem is that after refreshing the page I've got exception.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getChild() on a non-object

in this line:

```
$platform_filter=$this->getLayout()->getBlock('enterprisecatalog.leftnav')->getChild('platform_filter');
```

any idea how to fix that? I've spent 2 days on it and still cannot resolve it.

Comment: Good luck, would love to know your solution or anyone else who can help answer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem this way. I created the observer which exclude category view from FPC. It's not the best way because I needed only to exclude one block from this view but it works...

My observer:

```
class MyCompany_Catalog_Model_Observer
{
    public function processPreDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

        if ($action->getFullActionName() === 'catalog_category_view') {
            $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();         
            $cache->banUse('full_page');
        }
    }
}
```